# get strtotime of specific time in php

Tags: php, strtotime

I want to get the timestamp of a day/time for eg

```
17/12/2014 8pm
```

Currently I am doing

```
$curtime = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

which is giving me the current timestamp but I need to be of 8pm.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you just trying to format it differently?

Comment: All I want it to be in this format -- 1418823780

Comment: With your method, `$curtime = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"). ' 20:00:00');` but it's not a very good method.

Comment: Thanks @sjagr let me try

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're trying to get a timestamp of today at 8pm, it's actually much more simple than using `date` since you can use relative times in a `strtotime`:

```
$curtime = strtotime('today 8pm');
```

If you test this with `date`:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $curtime); // Returns 2014-12-17 20:00:00
```

Here's a whole writeup on [relative date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) that explains how you can construct proper relative dates.

Comment: Awesome...I just can't believe it can be that simple.

Comment: @Raj Yeah! You can use some pretty common English wordings, like `next Friday 8pm` or `yesterday 8pm`. Or you can reduce the ambiguity and use `+1 day 8pm` for tomorrow at 8pm.

Comment: Something like english language :D

Comment: Thank goodness for this post. I was driving myself crazy trying things like `3pm today` instead of `today 3pm`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using [date_create_from_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php). Checking out format's parameters, you will end up with something like this:

```
    $date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y ga', '17/12/2014 8pm');
    if (!empty($date)) {//returns false if can't create date
        $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
        //echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $timestamp);
    }
```